# Delete a node from xml file selected from a listbox C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

i'm trying to delete a node, in a xml file, its name is given by a listbox(in the list box is shown only the  of every setting and i need to delete every setting under that name), i tried everything but i can't make it work. this is my list trying:

```
private void dlt_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string selectednode = Convert.ToString(listBox1.SelectedItem);

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("dati.txt");

        XmlNodeList nodes = doc.GetElementsByTagName(selectednode);
        XmlNode node = nodes[0];
        node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);

        doc.Save("dati.txt");
    }
```

and this is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DATA>
  <name>wewe4</name>
  <SETTING_LIST>
    <setting>
      <name>Ping</name>
      <enable>config</enable>
      <disable>config</disable>
      <check>config</check>
      <word>ping</word>
      <ifchecktrue>true</ifchecktrue>
      <usegrep>true</usegrep>
    </setting>
    <setting>
      <name>Pong</name>
      <enable>config</enable>
      <disable>config</disable>
      <check>config</check>
      <word>ping</word>
      <ifchecktrue>true</ifchecktrue>
      <usegrep>true</usegrep>
    </setting>
    </DATA>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit your post to include a clear problem description. Tell us what you have tried. For guidance please check the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The xml is invalid. Is `<SETTING_LIST>` actually part of the document or is that just a note you are communicating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood you, this is how you would do it with `System.Xml.Linq.XDocument`, **this code does not use `XmlDocument`**. `XDocument` is a newer API:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("dati.txt");

doc.Descendants().Elements("name")           //all "name" elements
    .Where(d => d.Value == selectednode)     //where node value is user input
    .Where(d => d.Parent.Name == "setting")  //and also its parent element name is "setting"
    .Select(d => d.Parent)                   //Select name's parent
    .Remove();                               //Remove it

//optionally save the xml back to the file or whatever you intend to do with it.
```